# Is there a tool to view the child class and all its attributes and methods inherited from multiple parents in Django / Python?

Tags: python, django, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm doing battle with Django's Class Based Views and their mixin inheritance at the moment. What would really help me to understand what is going on would be a way to "export" from my child class all its inheritances. What I mean, is a tool that would go through all the parent classes pulling out methods and attributes, overriding as necessary so that I could see the "Frankenstein" class constructed from all of the different parts in one file. I think that would make it easier to work out what is going on. Does anybody know of such a tool? I use PyCharm by the way if that helps.

Comment: Are you familiar with [CCBV](https://ccbv.co.uk)? it's a great resource for learning and as a reference

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you're looking for something more customizable to your project, but you can take a look at [Classy Django](https://ccbv.co.uk/) which does what you're looking for with Django's built-in class based views.

If that's not going to cut it, you can always install IPython and explore instances of each class or classes themselves by pressing the tab key to view all members on an instance/class.

Comment: The `__bases__` special attribute can be very useful btw when doing that.

Comment: Thanks @schillingt and spectras, I've installed IPython, I've tried the FormView% and FormView.__bases__ for example, but not sure when to press the period key. Classy Django looks very useful too

Comment: Sorry, the Tab button is what I meant.

Comment: Thanks, Classy Django is great, I was able to use it to sort my class out. It all hinges on the http method methods (get, post etc, doesn't it?) If only I could feed it a list of classes and it would work out the inheritance on the fly. The project is on [github](https://github.com/refreshoxford/django-cbv-inspector) so I will put in a feature request.